# How can I save table data ex: Min,max,avg,90%,throughput,etc

Tags: jmeter

How can I save table data(ex: min, max,avg,90%, throughput,etc..) for an aggregate report or summary report while running through command prompt in JMeter.

[image: iam attaching the screenshot-]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a csv/jtl/xml file in your Summary Report or Aggregate Report.
[image: SummaryReport]
Save your Jmeter script and execute it through cmd. Your results will be saved in the .csv file.

You can follow this [Save Response Data in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-save-response-data-in-jmeter)

Comment: @Nagarani, Is your query resoled ?

Comment: As you said above, Im able to save only few fields(timeStamp,elapsed,label,responseCode,responseMessage,threadName,dataType,success,failureMessage,bytes,sentBytes,grpThreads,allThreads,Latency,IdleTime,Connect) but i wanted to save Througput, Min,Max,avg,90%line,99%line,Median,Labels and samples

Answer (score 0):

If you want a text representation of the table data of the [Aggregate Report](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report) listener you can use [JMeterPluginsCMD Command Line Graph Plotting Tool](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeterpluginscmd-command-line), the relevant command would be something like:

```
JMeterPluginsCMD.bat --generate-csv aggregatereport.csv --input-jtl /path/to/your/test/result.jtl --plugin-type AggregateReport
```

You can install JMeter Plugins Command Line Tool using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

[image]